# stop automatic ANSI color formatting of a list in ipython jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have been generating a list with ipython jupyter notebook (macos 1015.7) by using !ls
ex. alldirs = !ls -d ./3*[_-]12*/processing*/

I was expecting (and want) this:

```
In [1]:]alldirs[:4]
Out [1]:
['./3ABC_125_20190116/processing_20190521/',
'./3ABC_125_20220909/processing_20221116/',
'./3ABC_125_20181016/processing_20190529/,
'./3ABC_125_20181112/processing_20190909']
```

Instead what I'm getting is the path + ANSI color formatting.

```
In [1]: alldirs[:4]
Out [1]:
['\x1b[34m./3ABC_125_20190116/processing_20190521/\x1b[m\x1b[m',
'\x1b[34m./3ABC_125_20220909/processing_20221116/\x1b[m\x1b[m',
'\x1b[34m./3ABC_125_20181016/processing_20190529/\x1b[m\x1b[m',
'\x1b[34m./3ABC_125_20181112/processing_20190909/\x1b[m\x1b[m']``
```

Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 7.31.1
ipykernel        : 6.19.2
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.4.9
jupyter_core     : 5.2.0
jupyter_server   : 1.23.4
jupyterlab       : 3.5.3
nbclient         : 0.5.13
nbconvert        : 6.5.4
nbformat         : 5.7.0
notebook         : 6.5.2
qtconsole        : 5.3.2
traitlets        : 5.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ls --color=never` option.

Also, many tools support `NO_COLOR` environment variable which you can set using:

```py
import os
os.environ["NO_COLOR"] = "True"
```

Comment: Thanks Igonato for the suggestions.  ls --color=never outputs an "illegal option" error and os.environ didn't fix the problem.  Using 'find'  or glob instead of 'ls' seems to be a work around.